# The rvm help command output looks strange

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

When I type in ubuntu terminal:

`$ rvm help use`

The command output looks like:

```
M-bM-^HM-4 rvm use [ruby-string]

Setup current shell to use a specific ruby version.
...
```

What are the `M-bM-^HM-4` characters? Should I use a special command to read the help?

Comment: Those look like colour codes which your terminal is apparently not set to interpret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are unicode characters:

```
∴ rvm list
```

Answer (score -1):

I see it too. Looks like it's just some weird characters that the documenter typed in before every instance of the term "rvm".

Likely on their console, it highlights the term, or something similar.

Comment: Yeah -- I have it too. I thought maybe it was some kind of colorizing thing or something? But that doesn't appear to be true, because the colors show up in green at the end correctly...